# Can't Update Values In Microsoft Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have a problem that when I try updating data the the program doesn't save it in the database.

This is the current code:

```
Dim y As Byte = Convert.ToByte(lblID.Text) - 1
Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
ds.Tables("dset").Rows(y).Item(1) = txtname.Text
ds.Tables("dset").Rows(y).Item(2) = txtsubm.Text & "/" & txtsubd.Text & "/" & txtsuby.Text
ds.Tables("dset").Rows(y).Item(3) = txtexpm.Text & "/" & txtexpd.Text & "/" & txtexpy.Text
ds.Tables("dset").Rows(y).Item(5) = txtnotes.Text
If MdComboBox1.SelectedItem = "A" Then
    ds.Tables("dset").Rows(y).Item(4) = "A"
ElseIf MdComboBox1.SelectedItem = "B" Then
Else
    MdAlertBox1.Text = "Please Select A Class The Class Box"
    MdAlertBox1.Visible = True
End If
MdAlertBox1.Text = "Data Sucessfully Updated !"
MdAlertBox1.kind = MDAlertBox._Kind.Success
MdAlertBox1.Visible = True
getinfo.Start()
updatedata.Stop()
```

And the declared variables:

```
Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim DbProv As String = "PROVIDER=microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
Dim Src As String = " data source = c:\users\kingo\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WindowsApplication2\WindowsApplication2\BigGymDB.accdb"
Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim ds As New DataSet
```

Comment: Did you debug step by step? if yes does it go throuh all functions?

Comment: yes there is no errors at all and yes it goes

Comment: Where do you call `da.Update(ds.Tables("dset"))`?

Comment: How do you check they were updated?

Answer (score 0):

Put a `debug.print` to see the values you are passing to the Database. Like this:

```
    ds.Tables("dset").Rows(y).Item(2) = txtsubm.Text & "/" & txtsubd.Text & "/" & txtsuby.Text
    ds.Tables("dset").Rows(y).Item(3) = txtexpm.Text & "/" & txtexpd.Text & "/" & txtexpy.Text
    ds.Tables("dset").Rows(y).Item(5) = txtnotes.Text
    'your code ---^

    debug.print txtname.Text; txtsubm.Text & "/" & txtsubd.Text & "/" & txtsuby.Text; 
    debug.print txtnotes.Text; txtexpm.Text & "/" & txtexpd.Text & "/" & txtexpy.Text

    'your code ---v

    If MdComboBox1.SelectedItem = "A" Then
        ds.Tables("dset").Rows(y).Item(4) = "A"
    ElseIf MdComboBox1.SelectedItem = "B" Then
```

Then in two lines in the Immdiate Window, you should see whether these `txtsub.Text` and the other 3 inputs actually have something.

Comment: for sure they have values , in fact values are displayed in the form's labels after being updated but when i try to debug it again the older values appear  " they're not assigned to the database"

Comment: @AdhamOmar - by any chance, do you have `On Error Resume Next` somewhere in your code?